# Integration of vector valued functions

Tags: integration, vector-spaces

Suppose we have a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\psi:\mathbb{R}\mapsto V$ is a function. Is there any definition in general for the quantity $$\int_U\psi(x)dx$$for some $U\subset \mathbb{R}$?

I know that for example, in physics, I've been in classes where if $\psi$ can be written as $$\psi(x)=\sum_i\psi^i(x)\vec{v}_i$$where $\psi^i:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{v}_i$ is constant, one usually states $$\int_U\psi(x)dx=\sum_i\int_U\psi^i(x)dx\,\vec{v}_i$$

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [Bochner integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral), which extends the Lebesgue integral to Banach space valued functions.